# When creating new assets what should we put in base Url and document root file?

Tags: craft3

I am not able to figure out what to put in base url and document root url while making new assets in craft cms

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aliases for that. `@web` and `@webroot` are aliases which are included in Craft by default, `@web` is pointing to the base website url and `@webroot` is pointing to the document root file path (absolute path) respectively.